# DriverError when reading GeoPackage with geopandas

Tags: geopandas, geopackage, fiona

I develop an import system that supports popular geoformats.
Sometimes I get a DriverError reading GeoPackage files with geopandas, but at times it works well.

My code is simple:

```
gdf = gpd.read_file(file)
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "fiona/_shim.pyx", line 83,
> in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector
> File "fiona/_err.pyx", line 291, in
> fiona._err.exc_wrap_pointer fiona._err.CPLE_AppDefinedError: unable to
> open database file: this file is a WAL-enabled database. It cannot be
> opened because it is presumably read-only or in a read-only directory.

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> File "/path/backend/layers/services/load_data.py", line 47, in
> file_to_geodataframe
> gdf = gpd.read_file(file)
>
> File
> "/path/venv1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py", line
> 201, in _read_file
> with reader(path_or_bytes, **kwargs) as features:
>
> File "/path/venv1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fiona/collection.py",
> line 555, in **init**
>
> super(BytesCollection, self).**init**(self.virtual_file, vsi=filetype, **kwds)   File
> "/path/venv1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fiona/collection.py", line
> 162, in **init**
>
> self.session.start(self, **kwargs)
>
> File "fiona/ogrext.pyx", line 540, in fiona.ogrext.Session.start
>
> File "fiona/_shim.pyx", line 90, in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector
>
> fiona.errors.DriverError: unable to open database file: this file is a
> WAL-enabled database. It cannot be opened because it is presumably
> read-only or in a read-only directory.

What should I do? I'm make tests this with some files that have the same permissions and are placed in the same directory.

Why are some files readable and others not? Am I doing something wrong or is it a file problem?

Filepath:

> /homedir/uploads/8371906e-162c-42fc-b56d-5e434ae6878c.gpkg

**Update:**

**I found a solution that works for me.** The first argument in the read_file function is the file path or file object.

> filename : str, path object or file-like object
> Either the absolute or relative path to the file or URL to
> be opened, or any object with a read() method (such as an open file or StringIO)

I used file object and got this error. After I changed the first argument to the path reading worked as I expected.

Comment: SQLite supports different journal modes and one of those is WAL https://sqlite.org/wal.html. Read the whole document, it is also explaining the Read-Only databases. If a GeoPackage that is in WAL mode is read-write and it is placed into a media and directory with read-write rights then geopandas should be able to read it.

Comment: You can answer your own question : https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 4):

*Adding the OP's solution here so this thread is marked as answered:*

The first argument in the read_file function is the file path or file object.

> filename : str, path object or file-like object
> Either the absolute or relative path to the file or URL to
> be opened, or any object with a read() method (such as an open file or StringIO)

I used file object and got this error. After I changed the first argument to the path reading worked as I expected.

Comment: I had similar issue. I wrote a script using geopandas to open shapefiles(geojson and shp). It was able to read some files and some others not. It gave a similar error in th eoriginal post. By using the full name path  it worked/opened on all the files.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was raised in my case because the path where I wanted to save the gpkg doesn't exist. So creating the dir was enough to make it works

```
if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(destination_path)):
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(destination_path))
```